# creating Window in MFC

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

When I run a create window program, it exits after a small time and I'm unable to see that window. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post your code. How are you creating the window?

Answer (score 1):

After you call Create you should also call the function ShowWindow for the newly create window.
Something like:

```
CDialog myDialog;
myDialog.Create(MYDIALOG::IDD, this);
myDialog.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This will not keep the application running. We still haven't seen the code, but I'm willing to bet dollars to donuts that the asker is missing the *message loop* that keeps his program running. You have to either write the message loop yourself, or show the dialog as modal (in which case, it will have its own message lop).